# Independently checking if PostgreSQL server and client are installed

Tags: postgresql, psql, unix

How can I independently determine whether the PostgreSQL server and client are installed in the Unix-based system?

I believe running `psql --version` checks only for the PostgreSQL client.

Is `postgres --version` the way to check for the server installation?

Comment: You are assuming that the binaries are in the `PATH` for the current user, but that's not a guarantee. You are also assuming that the presence of a binary means the server is properly set, which is not guaranteed either.

Comment: There is no general answer. You will have to tell us how PostgreSQL is installed.